# Etiquetar datos a cada línea en gráfico con Matplotlib en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matplotlib

He creado un código que me permite dibujar una gráfica por coordenadas desde un listado **‘ingreso_datos’**, hasta aquí me grafica tal como lo programé, sin embargo, ahora al querer etiquetar cada dato a su respectiva línea del dibujo, no lo devuelve como quisiera.

Además, otro problema es que al colorear todas las líneas se me colorean del mismo color, lo que busco es que las líneas **‘Verticales’** se coloreen de un color y las **‘Horizontales’** de otro color.

(en la ilustración indico el cómo busco que se vea la gráfica).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#                                      |COORDENADAS [Inicial y final]|
#          Línea Dato  Tipo            | x(i)   y(i)    x(j)    y(j) |    Code Data
#             [Col0]  [Col1]           |[Col2] [Col3] [Col4]  [Col5] | [Col6]  [Col7]|

ingreso_datos = [[ 1,  'Verticales',       0,     0,      0,      3,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 2,  'Verticales',     4.5,     0,    4.5,      3,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 3,  'Verticales',    10.5,     0,   10.5,      3,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 4,  'Verticales',       0,     3,      0,      6,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 5,  'Verticales',     4.5,     3,    4.5,      6,   'E.Tr',    400],
                 [ 6,  'Horizontales',     0,     3,    4.5,      3,   'E.Tr',    400],
                 [ 7,  'Horizontales',   4.5,     3,   10.5,      3,   'E.Tr',    400],
                 [ 8,  'Horizontales',     0,     6,    4.5,      6,   'E.Tr',    400]] 

x = [] #--> Genero lista vacía de coordenadas para posteriormente hallar el 
y = [] #    máximo valor de la coordenada y establecer así los margenes de mi gráfico.

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):

    xi = ingreso_datos[i][2] # X inicial
    yi = ingreso_datos[i][3] # Y inicial
    xf = ingreso_datos[i][4] # X final
    yf = ingreso_datos[i][5] # Y final

    # Las coordenadas de mi dibujo
    x_coord = [xi, xf]
    y_coord = [yi, yf]

    # Aquí defino el plot de mi gráfico
    plt.plot(x_coord, y_coord,color='darkslateblue',linewidth=4, label='Línea: '+ingreso_datos[i][1]+' '+str(ingreso_datos[i][0]))
    plt.plot(x_coord, y_coord,color='darkslateblue',linewidth=4, label='Code Data: '+ingreso_datos[i][6]+' '+str(ingreso_datos[i][7]))
    plt.legend(loc=1)
    plt.title('Gráfica')
    plt.xlabel('Eje X')
    plt.ylabel('Eje Y')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.grid(color='silver',linestyle='-',linewidth=0.5)
```

Ilustración:
[image: ilustracionObjetivo]

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que cada tipo sea de un color debes hacer que el color sea condicional al mismo. Es decir, debes pasar al argumento `color` un color distinto en función del tipo.

Por lo que muestras en el resultado esperado, no quieres etiquetas, lo que buscas son anotaciones al lado de cada línea. Para ello usa `matplotlib.pyplot.annotate`, tendrás que ajustar la alineación y posición manualmente en función también del tipo de línea mediante condicionales.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#                                      |COORDENADAS [Inicial y final]|
#          Línea Dato  Tipo            | x(i)   y(i)    x(j)    y(j) |    Code Data
#             [Col0]  [Col1]           |[Col2] [Col3] [Col4]  [Col5] | [Col6]  [Col7]|

ingreso_datos = [[ 1,  'Verticales',       0,     0,      0,      3,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 2,  'Verticales',     4.5,     0,    4.5,      3,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 3,  'Verticales',    10.5,     0,   10.5,      3,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 4,  'Verticales',       0,     3,      0,      6,   'A.Pr',    450],
                 [ 5,  'Verticales',     4.5,     3,    4.5,      6,   'E.Tr',    400],
                 [ 6,  'Horizontales',     0,     3,    4.5,      3,   'E.Tr',    400],
                 [ 7,  'Horizontales',   4.5,     3,   10.5,      3,   'E.Tr',    400],
                 [ 8,  'Horizontales',     0,     6,    4.5,      6,   'E.Tr',    400]] 

for idx, tipo, xi, yi, xf, yf, code, data in ingreso_datos:
    plt.plot(
        (xi, xf),
        (yi, yf),
        color='blue' if tipo == "Verticales" else "red",
        linewidth=4
    )

    plt.annotate(f"Linea: {tipo} {idx}\nCode {code}, data {data}",
                 xy=(xi + (xf - xi) / 2, yi + (yf - yi) / 2),
                 textcoords="offset points",
                 xytext= (0, -15) if tipo == "Horizontales" else (5, 0),
                 ha='center' if tipo == "Horizontales" else "left", 
                 va="center")

plt.title('Gráfica')
plt.xlabel('Eje X')
plt.ylabel('Eje Y')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(color='silver',linestyle='-',linewidth=0.5) 
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado por la explicación detallada, saludos cordiales.